# Before_save event excel vb

Tags: excel, vba

Excel VB newbie. I know I must be missing something very simple. How do I get before_save event to work with more than one worksheet? Only one needs code. I have it in ThisWorkbook. It works if I only have one sheet in my workbook.

After seeing the comment that it doesn't matter if there's more than one worksheet I looked again at my code. I fixed the code and now the BeforeSave event will trigger and not save until all conditions are met like it's supposed to.

The BeforeSave event triggers if I put it in ThisWorkbook. But if I put it in Sheet1 and call the sub in ThisWorkbook, it still runs the sub like it's supposed to but doesn't prevent it from saving. Hoping this makes sense. I know the code is messy so please bear with me.

Sheet1:

```
Sub checkSheet1()

Dim cellCount As Variant, findEmpty As String, Counter%
allYellowCellsArray = Array(Range("C6"), Range("C7"), Range("C8"), Range("C9"), Range("C18"), Range("C19"), Range("C20"), Range("C21"), Range("C22"), Range("C29"), Range("C30"), Range("C31"), Range("C32"), Range("C33"), Range("C42"), Range("C62"))
noDateYellowCellsArray = Array(Range("C6"), Range("C7"), Range("C8"), Range("C9"), Range("C18"), Range("C19"), Range("C20"), Range("C21"), Range("C22"), Range("C29"), Range("C30"), Range("C31"), Range("C32"), Range("C33"), Range("C42"))
emptyCell = ""
Counter = 0  

Debug.Print vbNewLine & "List the values of each cell in the array:"
'count number of yellow/empty cells
For Each cellCount In allYellowCellsArray  
Debug.Print cellCount.Address() & " value is " & cellCount & " and color is " & cellCount.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    If cellCount = emptyCell Then
        Counter = Counter + 1
    End If
Next

'If-Then statements to alert how many yellow cells are still empty.
If Counter >= 1 Then
    MsgBox "(" & Counter & ") Mandatory Cells Have Not Been Completed", vbExclamation, "Missing Information"
    'cellCount = "Enter Missing Information"
End If

For Each cellCount In noDateYellowCellsArray
    If cellCount.Value = "" Then
        cellCount.Value = "Enter Missing Information"
    End If
Next

'Evaluate all yellow cells to prevent empty cells and make sure the set values have been changed ----
Dim cellValue As Variant
Dim fieldsAreYellow As Boolean
fieldsAreYellow = True
Dim redCellColor As Boolean
redCellColor = True
Dim cellCellColor As Variant

Debug.Print vbNewLine & "List cells that are red:"
For Each cellCellColor In allYellowCellsArray  'check for red cells
    If cellCellColor.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = 255 Then  'if cell background color is red
        redCellColor = True
        Debug.Print cellCellColor.Address() & " is " & cellCellColor.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
        Cancel = True
    End If

    If redCellColor = False Then
        MsgBox "There are no more red cells."
        Cancel = True
    End If
Next cellCellColor

Dim cellCountRedCells As Variant, redCellCounter%
redCellCounter = 0

For Each cellCountRedCells In allYellowCellsArray
    If cellCountRedCells.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = 255 Then  'red
        redCellCounter = redCellCounter + 1
        Debug.Print "redCellCounter is " & redCellCounter
        'MsgBox "redCellCounter is " & redCellCounter
    End If
Next

Debug.Print "redCellCounter is " & redCellCounter

'Check to see if cells in array have been changed
Debug.Print vbNewLine & "List the current background color of the first non-numeric cell that stopped the loop:"
For Each cellValue In allYellowCellsArray
    If cellValue = "Enter Missing Information" Then
        Debug.Print vbNewLine & cellValue
        fieldsAreYellow = False
        Debug.Print cellValue.Address() & " color is " & cellValue.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
        MsgBox "Check all of your cells for correct information." & vbNewLine & "There are still (" & redCellCounter & ") red cells.", vbCritical, "SAVE CANCELLED"
        Cancel = True  ' ** prevent the file from being saved **
    Exit For
    End If       
Next cellValue

'Final check
If (fieldsAreYellow = True) And (redCellCounter = 0) Then
    MsgBox "The document will be saved." & vbNewLine & "Remember the naming convention." & vbNewLine & "Customer_PIP Seal Calculator_Part Number rev#_Part Name_DDMMYY", vbInformation, "Good to Go!"
    Cancel = False 'allow save
Else:
    MsgBox "This file will not save until all of the cells have correct information.", vbCritical, "SAVE CANCELLED"
    Cancel = True 'cancel save
End If

End Sub
```

ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Call Sheet1.checkSheet1

End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with your code; see [reprex].

Comment: There is not any connection between the number of worksheets and `Workbook_BeforeSave` event. What "to work" should meant? To be triggered, or to do something you want  but the code does not do it? In order to understand that, as BigBen mentioned, you must show us your code.

Comment: @FaneDuru see my updates above. Hopefully it makes more sense. I know the code is messy.

Comment: Of course, it cannot stop if you try it as you say. `Cancel` is an argument of `Workbook_BeforeSave`. In your called `Sub`, `Cancel` it is not even declared. It does not have anything to do with the event. I cannot understand why you want it to be run in the sheet module, but if you insist, your `Sub` must be transformed in a function returning `Boolean`. And called as `Cancel = Sheet1.checkSheet1`. And take care to finally return `True` if you want the saving to be cancelled/stopped.

Comment: A terrible solution, but it should do the trick: Change your `Sub...` to `Function checkSheet1() As Boolean`. At the bottom (the last line) add `checkSheet1 = Cancel` and in `Workbook_Open` use `Cancel = Sheet1.checkSheet1`. A friendly advice: Never write code without `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules. This can be automatically written to all modules if you check `Require Variable Declarations` in `VBE>Tools>Options>Editor`. It will force you to declare all variables. Do not use `%`... etc. for types but rather use only `As Long` for whole, and `As Double` for decimal numbers.

Comment: @FaneDuru I put the sub in the sheet1 because there are other sheets I need to do the same validation process with. My thought was it probably wasn't best practice to have subs for multiple worksheets in ThisWorkbook.

Comment: This is not the best idea, I think. Anyhow, if you need to do that, you have to call the same function in all involved sheets. But you have to make the MsgBox referring to the problematic sheet, in order to know where the problem is... You can do that in a simpler way, in the code from its normal location. You can iterate between all sheets and process the ones you put in an array. Everything will work the same, but for the iterated sheet.

Answer (score 1):

I created a new excel file and tested this event. It works perfectly on both sheets.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "OK"
End Sub
```

I suggest to try this on a new file and then copy your code to the new file.

[image: VBA]

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the event was as you need, the called `Sub` must be transformed in a `Function` returning `Boolean`.

The event code should look like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = Sheet1.checkSheet1
End Sub
```

And the called function, like this:

```
Public Function checkSheet1() As Boolean
   If 1 = 1 Then
        MsgBox "The saving cannot take place..."
        checkSheet1 = True 'instead of Cancel = True in the Sub
   Else
        checkSheet1 = False
   End If
End Function
```

You must adapt your code to finally return something like `checkSheet1 = Cancel`. But take care to properly declare `Dim Cancel as Boolean`...

If something unclear, please, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications. If you need me to transform your existing `Sub`, I can do it, but I think it is better for you do do that, in order to understand the meaning and learn...

Comment: @Joanna Schweiger Didn't you find some time to test the received answers...?

Answer (score 0):

### Loop Through Worksheets In BeforeSave

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    ' Create a list of worksheet names.
    Const wsList As String = "Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3"
    Dim nms() As String       ' Declare an array of type 'String'.
    nms = Split(wsList, ",")  ' Write the list to the array.
    Dim ws As Worksheet       ' Declare a worksheet variable.
    Dim n As Long             ' Declare a 'counter' variable of type 'Long'.
    ' Loop through the elements (names) in the array.
    For n = 0 To UBound(nms)
        ' Define current worksheet.
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(nms(n))
        ' Do something, e.g. write some text to cell 'A1' and autofit column 'A'.
        ws.Range("A1").Value = "Testing worksheet '" & ws.Name & "'."
        ws.Columns("A").AutoFit
    Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: @FaneDuru I have to work on another project today but I will try to do more with it tomorrow. I think I understand how to modify it based on your suggestions. It makes sense now why BeforeSave triggered when I had the code in ThisWorkbook vs Sheet1. Thank you so much for your help! I'm sure I will have more questions! I also want to do a couple more things before it saves that may be handled with an If-Then, but one step at a time. :)

Comment: @Joanna Schweiger No problem with me, but you should comment on my answer, without a need to tag me... I would like to receive some feedback after you test it.